# Firestore and bloom filters to avoid repetition

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, bloom-filter

I am creating a tinder style app in which users are shown to one another and either liked or disliked.

I am using Firestore from firebase along with ionic 3 to achieve this. so far Firestore has been perfect and I have been able to do everything required using it.

However now I am at the stage where I need to ensure a user is not displayed to another user after they have been swiped once.

Cureently i query Firestore as follows:

```
this.firestore.col$('Users', ref =>
  ref.where(interests.<INTEREST CHOSEN BY USER>, '>', 0)
    .limit(30))
```

This returns a list of users with interests the same as the user who is swiping and i want to ensure once they have been swiped once, that user is never shown again.

I tried using the field createdBy to achieve this, by saving the most recent date, and then querying for results that have a createAt date, after this, however Firestore does not allow comparisons on more than one field in one query.

Bloom filters seem to be the way to achieve what i need. I am wondering the best way to approach this.

Option 1:
Save a bloom filter into a users record and compare query results to this when they are downloaded, and filter out using map function.

I have not used bloom filters before, and am not sure how to best approach this when using firestore.

Is there a better approach to take?

Comment: did you ever get this solved?

Comment: I ended up using bloomfilters. Theres a bloomfilter for NPM. Not the best way but I saved a bloomfilter for each user, and then used this every time they logged in.

Comment: any chance you can point me to the resources you used to learn bloom filters? I like you am a newbie with them

Comment: https://github.com/jasondavies/bloomfilter.js/ - the code.

Comment: https://www.jasondavies.com/bloomfilter/ - the guide.

Comment: Did you ever get further with this? Are you downloading the whole bloom filter, than downloading the users and then filtering them out or are you querying through the bloom filter?